# time picker dialoge doesn't show

Tags: android

am doing a to-do list app and when it comes to the time picker it doesn't show I wanted to work when we click on a certain button the time picker show and the selected value appears in the edit text

I've looked on the youtube tried some things same results

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
    {
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int min = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), (TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener) getActivity(), hour, min, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int i, int i1)
    {
        String time = i + " : " + i1;
        timeTxt.setText(time);
    }
//and this is the button code 
timeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                DialogFragment timePicker = new TimePickerFragment();
                timePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timepicker");
            }
        });
```

what happens is that I have no errors but it is a run time error and the app stops

Comment: Please provide crash log

Comment: i'm kinda new in the android so where can i find this crash log

Comment: Click Logcat on left bottom corner of Android Studio

Comment: i did and so much have appeared u want it all, or what i'm kinda confused here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should be in activity you are calling the timepicker. Place the button in activity and then call listner.

```
timeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                DialogFragment timePicker = new TimePickerFragment();
                timePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timepicker");
            }
        });
```

Comment: the 2 classes are in the main class and the button in the on create

Comment: @SeifTarek remove this code from TimePickerFragmentClass. Create button in your main activity or wherever you want to show timepicker , then implement this listener there.If you remove this you will see the app will not crash. Let me know